# What is Haskell not happy about? It's complaining about my type signature

Tags: function, haskell, types, constructor

I've another issue with my Haskell. I'm given the following data constructor from a problem,

```
type Point = (Int, Int)

data Points = Lines Int Int
            | Columns Int Int
            | Union Points Points
            | Intersection Points Points
```

It's about points on a grid starting (0,0) and (x,y) has x as the horizontal distance from the origin and y  as the vertical distance from the origin.

I tried to define a function "Lines" from this, which, given Lines x y would evaluate all points with vertical distance x ~ y on the grid. 
e.g.

```
> Lines 2 4 
(0,2)(1,2)(2,2)(3,2)....
(0,3)(1,3)(2,3)(3,3)....
(0,4)(1,4)(2,4)(3,4)....
```

and so on. Well what I did, was,

```
Lines :: Int -> Int -> Points
Lines lo hi = [ (_, y) | lo <= y && y <= hi ]
```

But Haskell complains that;

> Invalid type signature Lines :: Int -> Int -> Points.
>       Should be of the form  ::

what's this mean? "Points" is defined above already...surely "Int" "Points" are regarded as "types"? I don't see the problem, why is Haskell confused?

Comment: Where do x values come from in `lines`? Do you want to construct a list of infinite lists? Then try `lines' lo hi = map (\y -> map (\x -> (x, y)) [0..]) [lo..hi]`. Note there is already a function called `lines`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Functions must not start with a capital letter. So you need to use `lines`, not `Lines`. This is probably the source of the error message you're seeing.
2. The syntax `[ ... ]` is for creating a *list* of results, but your type signature claims that the function returns `Points`, which isn't any kind of list. If you meant to return a list of `Point` values, that's the `[Point]` type.
3. I have literally no idea what your implementation of `Lines` is even trying to do. The syntax makes no sense to me.

---

OK, so taking your comments into account...

- You can generate a list of numbers between `lo` and `hi` by writing `[lo .. hi]`.
- You say an "arbitrary" value can go in X, but you need to pin down exactly what that means. Your example seems to suggest you want the numbers from 0 upwards, forever. The way to generate that list is `[0 .. ]`. (Not giving an upper limit makes the list endless.)
- Your example suggests you want a list of lists, with the inner list containing all points with the same Y-coordinate paired with all possible X-coordinates.

So here is one possible way to do that:

```
type Point = (Int, Int)

lines :: Int -> Int -> [[Point]]
lines lo hi = [ [(x,y) | x <- [0..]] | y <- [lo .. hi] ]
```

That's perhaps a teeny bit hard to read, with all those opening and closing brackets, so perhaps I can make it slightly cleaner:

```
lines lo hi =
  let
    xs = [0..]
    ys = [lo .. hi]
  in [    [(x,y) | x <- xs]    | y <- ys]
```

If you run this, you get

```
> lines 2 4
[[(0,2), (1,2), (2,2), ...],
[(0,3), (1,3), (2,3), ...],
[(0,4), (1,4), (2,4), ...]]
```

In other words, the outer list has 3 elements (Y=2, Y=3 and Y=4), and each of the three inner lists is infinitely long (every possible positive X value).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! okay I'll try to fix the capital into a lower case...well the >Lines is just trying to generate a set of points (Int,Int) given lo,hi. (_,y) meaning that arbitrary numbers go into the x entry, and y is more than or equal to lo, less than or equal to hi. At least that is what I intended there....never ever done programming in my life and I am really unconfident about my skills...

Comment: @Brad List comprehension syntax is basically `xs = [val | val < someList, boolean guards]`.  In English, xs is a list of values such that each value is drawn from a list, named `someList` filtering out any value that fails the boolean guards.  Haskell will not magically invent values for you, you must explicitly specify the `x` instead of using an underscore and you must specify the base list.  So perhaps `lines lo hi = [ (1,y) | y <- [1..], y >= lo, y <= hi]`.

Comment: I would bet what's actually wanted is `lines lo hi = [(x, y) | y <- [0..], x <- [lo..hi]]`. (N.B. a single layer of list, and transposed iteration order)